# Number of solutions of: $3x+y=5702$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, linear-diophantine-equations

> Find the number of ordered pairs $(x,y)$ satisfying  $3x+y=5702$ in
>   natural numbers restricted by: $x+y\le2003$

I don't know any method for counting number of solutions of such equations...

Comment: Just figure it out carefully. What is the *smallest* $x$ that will work?

Comment: I think it is: $1233$

Comment: Correct! What is the largest?

Comment: @almagest It is 1900,now may we deduce that the answer is : 1900-1233+1?

Comment: Correct again! And will any number in that range work (meaning that it will give $0\le y\le 2003$)?

Comment: Yes, $x=1233$ gives $y=2003$ and $x=1900$ gives $y=2$ but maybe some answers between $1233$ and $1900$ are not acceptable

Comment: @almagest I wrote a C# program and calculated the exact result as: $51$ !!! Now I'm sure many of numbers in range 1233 to 1900 don't satisfy  our conditions.But which of them and why?

Comment: @HamidRezaEbrahimi There are way more than $51$ solutions. For example, $x=1300, 1301, 1302,\dots 1351$ and $y=802, 799, 796, \dots, 649$ are $52$ specific solutions to the problem, and they all satisfy the conditions.

Comment: @HamidRezaEbrahimi Sorry, I thought the condition was $x,y\le2003$. It is $x+y\le2003$, so yes the number is 51.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll find all the integer solutions of $3x+y=5702$.

First, mod $3$ gives $y\equiv 2\pmod{3}$. Let $y=3k+2$, $k\in\mathbb Z$.
$$3x+3k+2=5702\iff 3(x+k)=5700$$ $$\iff x+k=1900\iff x=1900-k$$

All the integer solutions are $(x,y)=(1900-k,3k+2)$, $k\in\mathbb Z$.

$$x+y=(1900-k)+(3k+2)$$

$$=2k+1902\le 2003$$

$$\iff k\le 50.5\iff k\le 50$$

Natural numbers have different definitions among different authors (they do or don't include $0$; see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number) or [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NaturalNumber.html)).

Assuming $0\in\mathbb N$, you want to find all $k\in\mathbb Z$ such that $1900-k\ge 0$, $3k+2\ge 0$, $k\le 50$.

You'll get $k\in\{0,1,2,\ldots,50\}$, which will generate all the $(x,y)$ that the problem is asking about.

I.e., all the needed pairs are $$(x,y)\in\{(1900,2),(1899,5),(1898,8),\ldots,(1850,152)\}$$ There are $51$ such pair.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

Well, there's one solution for $x=1$, and one for $x=2$, and another for $x=3$ and so on.

Now, that would give you infinitely many solutions, but you have two restrictions:

1. $x$ and $y$ are natural numbers, so they are greater than $0$.
2. The sum of $x$ and $y$ must be smaller than $2003$, so that disqualifies $x=1, y=5699$, for example.

Can you continue from here to determine all solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a first overview:

[image: Overview]
([Large version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZEkF.png))

It shows the constaints $x \ge 1$, $y \ge 1$, $x+y\le 2003 \, (*)$ (the blue coloured half-space) and the line $3x + y = 5702$ (black diagonal line).

We see that the solutions lie on the last points of the line. below $y = 200$ (yellow line) and not lower than $y = 1$.

The line enters the region of constraint $(*)$ at the intersection of
$$
x + y = 2003 \\
3x + y = 5702 
$$
which means
$$
x + y = 2003 \\
-2y = -307
$$
or
$$
x = 1849.5 \\
y = 153.5
$$

To lie on the grid $\mathbb{Z}^2$ we need $x = (5702 - y) / 3$ to be a whole number, or
$$
5702 - y = 3 k \quad (k \in \mathbb{Z}) \iff \\
0 
= (5702 - y) \bmod 3 
= ((5702 \bmod 3) - (y \bmod 3)) \bmod 3
= (2 - y \bmod 3) \bmod 3 \iff \\
y \bmod 3 = 2 \iff \\
y = 2 + 3 k \quad (k \in \mathbb{Z})
$$
So the first solution is $((5702 - 152)/3, 152) = (1850, 152)$, as $y=153$ is not on the grid.
And the last solution is $((5702-2)/3,2) = (1900, 2)$.

All solutions are
$$
\{ (5702 -(2 + 3k))/3, 2 + 3k) \mid k \in \{ 0, \dots, 50 \} \} = \\
\{ (1900-k, 2 + 3k) \mid k \in \{ 0, \dots, 50 \} \}
$$
and we count $51$ of them.